# Where should I convert the birth_date string to a Date object?

Tags: api

My angular module resolve object:

```
        resolve: {
      myContact: function(crmApi) {             
         return crmApi('Contact', 'getsingle', {
             //id: 'user_contact_id', 
             id: 43,
          return: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name', 'birth_date', 'gender_id']
        });
      }
    }
```

Which I am trying to bind to

```
            <input type="date"
          crm-ui-id="tournamentForm.birth_date"
          name="birth_date"
          ng-model="myContact.birth_date"
          placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" 
          min="1930-01-01" 
          max="2029-12-31" 
          />
```

Results in this error from angular:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `1972-05-11` to be a date
```

Where should I (what's the best practice for) convert the string to a Date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular example using the same options with data model binding:

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/ui/#date-picker

Comment: Did you solve your own question? If so you could mark your answer as solved?